# How display the values of text area dynamically on change?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have HTML code that looks like this:

```html
<textarea id="MyId"></textarea>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```

I want to display the contents below the text area dynamically. Just like while typing a question in the stack overflow.

I tried this:

```js
function Func(){
    document.getElementByID("MyDiv").innerHTML = document.getElementByID("MyId").innerHTML
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: You need to attach an event listener to the textarea, so that when an `input` event is fired from the textarea, you will set the innerHTML of `#myDiv` to the value of the textarea.

Comment: Textareas have a `.value`.

Comment: `getElementByID` is not a function

Comment: @Terry Can you please add it as an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This worked! Thanks @Terry

```js
const input = document.getElementById('MyId');
const log = document.getElementById('MyDiv');

function updateValue(e) {
  log.textContent = e.target.value;
}
input.addEventListener('input', updateValue);
```

Comment: Don't listen to the `keyup` event. `input` will be much better.

Comment: Thanks again!! `input` is better ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Attach a listener for the `input` event and inside it use `innerText` to handle line breaks properly and get the text using `.value`. Also you made a typo: `getElementById` has a lowercase `d`.

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById("myId"),
div = document.getElementById("myDiv");

textarea.addEventListener("input", ev => {
  div.innerText = textarea.value;
});
```

```html
<textarea id="myId"></textarea>
<div id="myDiv"></div>
```